# elasticsearch-py 2.4.0 for python does not contain delete_by_query() function.

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

elasticsearch-py 2.4.0 for python does not contain delete_by_query() function. So How can I delete documents based on the query in elasticsearch 2.4.0 library?

Answer (score 0):

From Elasticsearch version 2.x, delete_by_query feature has been removed and moved as plugin. Reference [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/delete-by-query-plugin-reason.html)

If you want to delete multiple documents using python, use [bulk helpers](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html)

Generate the list of document ids using search query and pass the list to bulk delete.